# How to send and receive data from jQuery.post in Facebook using Console Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, sdk

If you go on facebook and run this script to the console:

```
window.boxbigG = new Dialog();
mainDlg.showLoading();  
var js, ref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    js = document.createElement('script');
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);

jQuery.post("http://google.it", {
            q: "test"
        }, function (data) {
            boxbigG.setBody(data);
            boxbigG.show();
        });
```

why dont work?

PS: allow not secure content http because facebook use https.

-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-/-

I tried to put in

```
console.log(data)
```

in

```
function(data){}
```

and

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
json_encode($data_out_array); exit;
```

but do not return anything.

I also added a simple-log in php file

```
$fp = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
fwrite($fp, $_POST[q]."\n");
fclose($fp);
```

and the log is written it does not work function (data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED: in php file i have add this

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do remote POSTs to another server due to Origin policies. Your code can only call pages within your site's domain, e.g:

`http://test.com/index.php` can only call pages from `http://test.com/`. There are of course exceptions when you start using JSONp, but for your purposes you simply cannot do that.

**Edit:**

Don't forget to include the following line before any PHP echo that returns something you expect to be returned as JSON:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
json_encode($data_out_array); exit;
```

Comment: I use this script to send data to my website.
The data I receive them, but the function (data) does not receive my output.


<?php 
if(isset($_POST['q'])){
echo "ok";
?>

Comment: Your script may well be running from `apps.facebook.com` in which case it won't matter if you own the server or not, the domains are different and the browsers will not service the request.

Comment: Your missing a closing `}` on your `if(){}`

Comment: I'm sorry but I quickly wrote

Comment: Have you tried a `console.log(data)` inside your `function(data){}` and see what gets returned.

Comment: returns nothing, in my opinion is a problem of php file. Header()??